# Binding string between zig/wasm and JavaScript

Tags: zig

I used `i32` binding perfectly between zig/wasm and JavaScript as below:

```
//main.zig
const std = @import("std");
extern fn print(a: i32) void;

export fn add(a: i32, b: i32) i32 {
    print(a + b); // calling the JavaScript function
    return a + b;
}
```

Compiled it as:

```bash
zig build-lib -O ReleaseSmall -target wasm32-freestanding main.zig -dynamic
```

And called it from nodejs as:

```
// index.js
import fs from "fs"
const source = fs.readFileSync("main.wasm")
const tyoedArray = new Uint8Array(source)

const importObject = {
    env: {
        print: function(x) { console.log(x); } // map the zig function print to the JS function console.log(x)
    },
  };
  
const resuult = await WebAssembly.instantiate(tyoedArray, importObject);
console.log(`a + b = ${resuult.instance.exports.add(2,3)}`);
```

And got the output as:

```bash
5 // printed from Zig print(a + b); that is mapping with JavaScript print: function(x) { console.log(x); }
a + b = 5 // printed from Javascript console.log(`a + b = ${resuult.instance.exports.add(2,3)}`);
```

What if instead the `extern fn print(a: i32) void;` I want to defined a function signature as:

```
// new.zig
extern sayHello([]const u8) []const u8;
```

And mapping it with a JS function like:

```
//new.js
const importObject = {
    env: {
        print: sayHello(name) {  
                  return `Hello ${name}` 
               };
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to pass a pointer from wasm to js is as an i32. On the js side the wasm's memory/address space is contained in a buffer object and the pointer is an offset into that buffer. Here is an example with an i32 array rather than u8 but it's pretty much the same:

```
const N: u32 = 1024;
var buf: [N]i32 = undefined;

export fn getPtr() i32 {
    return @intCast(i32, @ptrToInt(&buf));
}

export fn getSize() i32 {
    return @intCast(i32, N);
}
```

And then on js side:

```
const myBuf = new Int32Array(
    result.instance.exports.memory.buffer, 
    result.instance.exports.getPtr(), 
    result.instance.exports.getSize()
);
```

For `u8` you'd want to use `Uint8Array` and then convert that into a string.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently published a library that generates bindings between Zig and TypeScript, whether you're targeting Wasm or Node-API native addons:

https://github.com/nelipuu/zbind

It automatically creates wrappers for the functions on Zig and TypeScript side, marshalling them through a stack where for example `[]const u8` is represented as separate values for pointer and length.